# Persisting unauthenticated user on AWS Cognito and AWS Amplify with React Native

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement AWS-Amplify in a React Native app so that events can be sent to Pinpoint for analytics. A user doesn't need to be signed in to use the app, so they would be unauthenticated with Cognito.

I am noticing that the identity of the unauthenticated user doesn't seem to persist, so when I close or uninstall the app, a new identity id is generated when I launch the app. [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) suggest that this should be cached, but it seems the cache is clearing out when using AWS Amplify.

Is there a way to set or reuse an identity id for a returning unauthenticated user on AWS-Amplify or Cognito so new identity ids don't get assigned ?

I looked through amazon-cognito-identity-js to see if there was a way to do this with an unauthenticated user and wasn't able to find what I am describing: [see here](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js).

I'm new to AWS Amplify/Cognito/Pinpoint in general, so any thoughts or suggestions to do something similar would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

This is a known issue in the AWS Amplify and should have been fixed in the latest version.

Comment: For your answer to be useful, you should provide some code.